# Cube.js time series excluding weekends

Tags: cube.js

I am using mongo db BI connector and trying to render date series charts using cube.js. Is there a way to apply time dimension with a date range and considering only business days?
Below are my sample cube schema and collection

```
cube(`Entries`, {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM db.entries`,    
    measures: {
      count: {
        type: `count`
      }
    },

    dimensions: {
      result: {
        sql: `result`,
        type: `string`
      },

      date: {
        sql: `date`,
        type: `time`
      },
    },
  });
```

Query :

```
{
     "measures": [
       "Entries.count"
      ],
      "timeDimensions": [
         {
            "dimension": "Entries.date",
            "granularity": "day"
         }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by introducing `weekdays` segment:

```
cube(`Entries`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM db.entries`,    
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    result: {
      sql: `result`,
      type: `string`
    },

    date: {
      sql: `date`,
      type: `time`
    },
  },

  segments: {
    weekdays: {
      sql: `DAYOFWEEK(${date}) <> 1 AND DAYOFWEEK(${date}) <> 7`
    }
  }
});
```

And use it in query like:

```
{
   "measures": [
     "Entries.count"
   ],
   "timeDimensions": [
       {
          "dimension": "Entries.date",
          "granularity": "day"
       }
   ],
   "segments": ["Entries.weekdays"]
}
```

To hide zero weekend values pass `fillMissingDates: false` when preparing the data:

```
resultSet.chartPivot({ fillMissingDates: false })
```

More info about segments here: https://cube.dev/docs/segments

Comment: Yep. The only way I can imagine is to pass `resultSet.pivot({ fillMissingDates: false })` and implement custom missing date filling that respects only weekdays.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes now it considers only week days entries in result set. But how can I tell the chartPivot() method of resultset object to consider same segmented time series?
passing pivotConfig object like resultSet.pivot({'fillMissingDates' : false}) to pivotChart() is excluding all days where there is no entry in my collection, Instead I want to exclude only weekends and snow 0 in case of a missed business date. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Yep. That's right. The only way I see right now is custom missing date filling implementation.

Comment: would not that require calling custom wrapper with each query result set from cube.js API ? Can we handle it at schema layer by adding a separate time dimension collection and somehow plot time series based on that with out the need to fill. Please suggest if this would be possible with cube.js or better ways of handling the problem

Comment: Custom missing date filling implementation should be done on client side. You can try to do it on schema level but it's much harder to do so. You can try to override `ResultSet.timeSeries()` method. I'll be the easiest approach I believe.